No scrollbar on overflow
I have a DIV that will have many lines of texts inside. There will always be overflow lines. Like this:


<div style='height:200px;overflow:scroll;overflow-y:visible'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce condimentum dui in nibh tincidunt, a luctus dolor lobortis. Donec pretium efficitur condimentum. Curabitur interdum sed dolor in pretium. Ut tempus egestas mauris at viverra. Proin ornare
  tempor libero tincidunt tempor. Aliquam porta dictum placerat. Duis aliquet lectus ligula, a laoreet enim aliquet sit amet. Morbi ut aliquet est. Suspendisse pretium tellus ut hendrerit egestas. Proin hendrerit sollicitudin convallis. Ut varius nisi
  sit amet quam vehicula, ac sagittis ligula commodo. Phasellus interdum dictum nisi at placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi quis velit fringilla, feugiat augue eget, condimentum sem.
  Pellentesque ullamcorper, risus at fringilla lacinia, felis sem faucibus leo, vehicula ultrices turpis velit vel diam. Quisque nisi leo, accumsan non dictum in, laoreet quis diam. Nullam lacinia massa nunc, non mollis nisi rutrum quis. Nullam ullamcorper
  eros neque, tristique tristique arcu vestibulum quis. Duis pretium sed felis non euismod. Praesent sagittis leo finibus ex vestibulum, vel iaculis augue finibus. Nulla convallis enim molestie erat fermentum, quis pulvinar dui faucibus. In semper ex
  ut tellus fermentum, non auctor risus accumsan. Curabitur blandit vitae mi id tempus. Mauris ultricies eu nulla vel vulputate. Maecenas sit amet tristique neque. Cras et nulla suscipit, maximus ipsum eu, molestie magna. Ut eget tellus turpis. Class
  aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce bibendum lorem dui, sed congue ipsum fermentum id. Praesent dapibus malesuada fringilla. Fusce non mauris ipsum. Curabitur bibendum turpis augue, eu cursus sapien
  sagittis vitae. Curabitur ac ante vel mi gravida aliquet. Quisque cursus facilisis justo. Aliquam nec tellus finibus, tempor odio nec, tristique ligula. Duis tristique tellus enim, id suscipit lacus volutpat et. Nullam gravida, lectus in euismod volutpat,
  sapien quam consequat est, nec imperdiet arcu orci vitae turpis. Phasellus sit amet metus eu justo vehicula ultrices. Praesent nisl ipsum, iaculis sed pulvinar id, varius nec elit. Etiam nibh elit, blandit vel justo quis, fringilla molestie mauris.
  Sed consectetur ligula aliquet velit efficitur, et accumsan massa pellentesque. Vivamus consequat pellentesque rhoncus. Morbi pellentesque tempus quam, ut viverra libero efficitur ut. Maecenas fringilla sapien ut diam congue, eu iaculis sem euismod.
  Donec venenatis, ante cursus pellentesque euismod, leo lacus feugiat arcu, a interdum purus massa id lacus. Cras ornare ultrices erat in luctus. Integer hendrerit faucibus faucibus. Ut hendrerit, erat non molestie molestie, ex dui hendrerit sapien,
  vel commodo sem ex accumsan velit. Pellentesque vel justo vel neque dignissim accumsan. Morbi ut elementum eros. Nulla vel rhoncus diam, eu posuere lectus. Curabitur quam nisl, semper ac quam ut, pellentesque eleifend tellus. Vestibulum eu arcu consequat,
  gravida risus quis, gravida eros. Quisque nec hendrerit diam, quis ornare velit. Aenean congue, augue vel tristique venenatis, dolor ligula suscipit tortor, in pulvinar purus tellus et purus. Donec finibus ut purus vitae rhoncus. Curabitur vel ante
  mattis, facilisis enim eget, tempus purus. Proin nec purus non massa consectetur iaculis. Vivamus bibendum ex eu mattis blandit. Quisque in blandit magna. Maecenas eleifend quis lorem in iaculis. Nulla eget euismod ante. Nullam vitae convallis nisi.
  Duis suscipit sed justo vitae facilisis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam dignissim lorem lacus, tincidunt tincidunt nibh finibus eu. Nullam interdum, libero vel mollis interdum, nisi purus
  imperdiet leo, eget viverra enim ex a sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam vitae orci metus. Integer imperdiet orci et risus vulputate hendrerit. Duis ut nunc a nisi faucibus ultrices eget non nisl. Class aptent taciti
  sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus sit amet neque a sapien mattis interdum. Nam a diam id nunc consectetur aliquam. Pellentesque vitae auctor massa. Maecenas quis dignissim ligula, ultrices fermentum dolor.
  Sed vel tellus vulputate, semper erat ac, pharetra nunc. Morbi dapibus tortor felis, non lobortis dui mattis in. Proin dolor urna, interdum eu dolor pellentesque, finibus varius purus. In ligula nunc, mattis vel tellus ut, ultrices venenatis felis.
  Aenean rutrum lacus nec velit dignissim faucibus. Suspendisse tempor interdum aliquam. Sed mollis sed ipsum at tristique. Morbi elementum molestie tortor sit amet sagittis. Proin vestibulum ante sed arcu auctor, ac feugiat lorem congue. Duis vestibulum
  orci commodo sem euismod, et ultrices felis porttitor. Vivamus interdum leo orci, vitae egestas odio pulvinar sit amet. Proin fermentum eros ut gravida imperdiet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Nulla justo metus, posuere ut sapien in, fermentum volutpat metus. Quisque ut justo vulputate, auctor mi tristique, dignissim neque. Curabitur volutpat auctor massa. Curabitur eget justo id libero ultricies accumsan. Pellentesque convallis justo ac
  mollis suscipit. Aenean eget mauris vestibulum, scelerisque arcu in, hendrerit neque. Nullam et dolor maximus, tincidunt urna vitae, tempus lorem. Ut iaculis et nisi et gravida. Maecenas cursus gravida lorem ut mattis. Fusce eget ultricies sem. Sed
  tincidunt justo eget odio vehicula, dictum sagittis lectus convallis. Cras nulla quam, consectetur vel sem eget, posuere posuere ligula. Nulla auctor sem et erat sollicitudin, ornare venenatis neque tincidunt. Pellentesque accumsan tincidunt congue.
  Pellentesque mattis egestas consectetur. Pellentesque ac massa pretium, porta nibh eu, cursus eros. Nunc nec justo quis neque iaculis auctor nec ac quam. Nulla rutrum nisi a semper molestie. Nam non ex a sapien maximus vulputate. Ut suscipit sed ante
  et viverra. Vivamus nunc nisl, facilisis nec viverra eget, dictum ac metus. Pellentesque semper libero a quam congue, tristique semper augue porttitor. Maecenas erat sapien, maximus eget dui et, blandit aliquam dui. Pellentesque euismod ut leo et commodo.
  Mauris venenatis turpis quis ex posuere, eget varius nisi efficitur. Integer tincidunt leo leo, eget bibendum arcu rutrum ut. Praesent sit amet purus eu lorem blandit suscipit a ut quam.
</div>



I want the scroll bar to always be present, just to alert the user that there are more, non-visible content, further down. However, the scroll bar only show up after I starts to scroll within the div.
Everywhere I looked, the code above should work, but unfortunately, it does not.
What am I missing here?

The posted snippet works as is, please revise your code to actually simulate your problem

I'm guessing you are having this problem in mobile browsers, not on desktop? If so - possible duplicate of Make scrollbar visible in mobile browsers

No, I have this problem on my desktop, both in Chrome and Safari. The scroll bar does  not show up in the snippet above. @DarkBee

Which OS are you using? Windows 11 has a different behavior than older versions when it comes to scrollbars -  Hover over the div and the scrollbar should be there. Possible you could try to use scrollbar-width

You can just add 'overflow-y:scroll' and the scrollbar will always be visible when the content of the div exceeds the height of the div.


<div style='height:200px;overflow:scroll;overflow-y:scroll'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce condimentum dui in nibh tincidunt, a luctus dolor lobortis. Donec pretium efficitur condimentum. Curabitur interdum sed dolor in pretium. Ut tempus egestas mauris at viverra. Proin ornare
  tempor libero tincidunt tempor. Aliquam porta dictum placerat. Duis aliquet lectus ligula, a laoreet enim aliquet sit amet. Morbi ut aliquet est. Suspendisse pretium tellus ut hendrerit egestas. Proin hendrerit sollicitudin convallis. Ut varius nisi
  sit amet quam vehicula, ac sagittis ligula commodo. Phasellus interdum dictum nisi at placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi quis velit fringilla, feugiat augue eget, condimentum sem.
  Pellentesque ullamcorper, risus at fringilla lacinia, felis sem faucibus leo, vehicula ultrices turpis velit vel diam. Quisque nisi leo, accumsan non dictum in, laoreet quis diam. Nullam lacinia massa nunc, non mollis nisi rutrum quis. Nullam ullamcorper
  eros neque, tristique tristique arcu vestibulum quis. Duis pretium sed felis non euismod. Praesent sagittis leo finibus ex vestibulum, vel iaculis augue finibus. Nulla convallis enim molestie erat fermentum, quis pulvinar dui faucibus. In semper ex
  ut tellus fermentum, non auctor risus accumsan. Curabitur blandit vitae mi id tempus. Mauris ultricies eu nulla vel vulputate. Maecenas sit amet tristique neque. Cras et nulla suscipit, maximus ipsum eu, molestie magna. Ut eget tellus turpis. Class
  aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce bibendum lorem dui, sed congue ipsum fermentum id. Praesent dapibus malesuada fringilla. Fusce non mauris ipsum. Curabitur bibendum turpis augue, eu cursus sapien
  sagittis vitae. Curabitur ac ante vel mi gravida aliquet. Quisque cursus facilisis justo. Aliquam nec tellus finibus, tempor odio nec, tristique ligula. Duis tristique tellus enim, id suscipit lacus volutpat et. Nullam gravida, lectus in euismod volutpat,
  sapien quam consequat est, nec imperdiet arcu orci vitae turpis. Phasellus sit amet metus eu justo vehicula ultrices. Praesent nisl ipsum, iaculis sed pulvinar id, varius nec elit. Etiam nibh elit, blandit vel justo quis, fringilla molestie mauris.
  Sed consectetur ligula aliquet velit efficitur, et accumsan massa pellentesque. Vivamus consequat pellentesque rhoncus. Morbi pellentesque tempus quam, ut viverra libero efficitur ut. Maecenas fringilla sapien ut diam congue, eu iaculis sem euismod.
  Donec venenatis, ante cursus pellentesque euismod, leo lacus feugiat arcu, a interdum purus massa id lacus. Cras ornare ultrices erat in luctus. Integer hendrerit faucibus faucibus. Ut hendrerit, erat non molestie molestie, ex dui hendrerit sapien,
  vel commodo sem ex accumsan velit. Pellentesque vel justo vel neque dignissim accumsan. Morbi ut elementum eros. Nulla vel rhoncus diam, eu posuere lectus. Curabitur quam nisl, semper ac quam ut, pellentesque eleifend tellus. Vestibulum eu arcu consequat,
  gravida risus quis, gravida eros. Quisque nec hendrerit diam, quis ornare velit. Aenean congue, augue vel tristique venenatis, dolor ligula suscipit tortor, in pulvinar purus tellus et purus. Donec finibus ut purus vitae rhoncus. Curabitur vel ante
  mattis, facilisis enim eget, tempus purus. Proin nec purus non massa consectetur iaculis. Vivamus bibendum ex eu mattis blandit. Quisque in blandit magna. Maecenas eleifend quis lorem in iaculis. Nulla eget euismod ante. Nullam vitae convallis nisi.
  Duis suscipit sed justo vitae facilisis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam dignissim lorem lacus, tincidunt tincidunt nibh finibus eu. Nullam interdum, libero vel mollis interdum, nisi purus
  imperdiet leo, eget viverra enim ex a sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam vitae orci metus. Integer imperdiet orci et risus vulputate hendrerit. Duis ut nunc a nisi faucibus ultrices eget non nisl. Class aptent taciti
  sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus sit amet neque a sapien mattis interdum. Nam a diam id nunc consectetur aliquam. Pellentesque vitae auctor massa. Maecenas quis dignissim ligula, ultrices fermentum dolor.
  Sed vel tellus vulputate, semper erat ac, pharetra nunc. Morbi dapibus tortor felis, non lobortis dui mattis in. Proin dolor urna, interdum eu dolor pellentesque, finibus varius purus. In ligula nunc, mattis vel tellus ut, ultrices venenatis felis.
  Aenean rutrum lacus nec velit dignissim faucibus. Suspendisse tempor interdum aliquam. Sed mollis sed ipsum at tristique. Morbi elementum molestie tortor sit amet sagittis. Proin vestibulum ante sed arcu auctor, ac feugiat lorem congue. Duis vestibulum
  orci commodo sem euismod, et ultrices felis porttitor. Vivamus interdum leo orci, vitae egestas odio pulvinar sit amet. Proin fermentum eros ut gravida imperdiet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Nulla justo metus, posuere ut sapien in, fermentum volutpat metus. Quisque ut justo vulputate, auctor mi tristique, dignissim neque. Curabitur volutpat auctor massa. Curabitur eget justo id libero ultricies accumsan. Pellentesque convallis justo ac
  mollis suscipit. Aenean eget mauris vestibulum, scelerisque arcu in, hendrerit neque. Nullam et dolor maximus, tincidunt urna vitae, tempus lorem. Ut iaculis et nisi et gravida. Maecenas cursus gravida lorem ut mattis. Fusce eget ultricies sem. Sed
  tincidunt justo eget odio vehicula, dictum sagittis lectus convallis. Cras nulla quam, consectetur vel sem eget, posuere posuere ligula. Nulla auctor sem et erat sollicitudin, ornare venenatis neque tincidunt. Pellentesque accumsan tincidunt congue.
  Pellentesque mattis egestas consectetur. Pellentesque ac massa pretium, porta nibh eu, cursus eros. Nunc nec justo quis neque iaculis auctor nec ac quam. Nulla rutrum nisi a semper molestie. Nam non ex a sapien maximus vulputate. Ut suscipit sed ante
  et viverra. Vivamus nunc nisl, facilisis nec viverra eget, dictum ac metus. Pellentesque semper libero a quam congue, tristique semper augue porttitor. Maecenas erat sapien, maximus eget dui et, blandit aliquam dui. Pellentesque euismod ut leo et commodo.
  Mauris venenatis turpis quis ex posuere, eget varius nisi efficitur. Integer tincidunt leo leo, eget bibendum arcu rutrum ut. Praesent sit amet purus eu lorem blandit suscipit a ut quam.
</div>



